# Custom "created_at" column Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby on Rails but I wonder if there is possibility to change default name of "created_at" column (a attribute used to store date and time of creation of new object) to column named eg. "published_at" with no change in its functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. The following fields have a special meaning in Rails

- `created_at`, `created_on`
- `updated_at`, `updated_on`

This convention is hard-coded in several parts of the ActiveRecord codebase and, as of ActiveRecord 3.1, this behavior is not configurable using settings.

If one (or more) of these fields exist, it is updated on creation/modification of a record. You need to find a different name for your functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't attempt to change the timestamps... In the future, you may want to implement publish as a status. So, today, you can

```
class YourModel
  alias published_at created_at  
end

YourModel.first.published_at
```

Then in the future, you can "promote' published_at to it's own functionality.

Comment: I have table with attributes id (primary key), label, created_at, published_at, updated_at and I want to use created_at as regular datetime column and published_at with original functionality of created_at. I'm not sure if your solution can solve my problem.

Comment: In your example, what functionality will "created_at" provide? If it is not the date-time that your model was created, I highly recommend you rethink what you're trying to do.